# Error [ a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ] in importing CSV to DynamoDB using python

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, python-3.7

I am trying to read a CSV file and import data in CSV to DynamoDB. First, I am going to store the CSV file in s3 buckets. Then I read the S3 in CSV and import those data to DynamoDB using an AWS Lambda function. I used the following Python script in the Lambda function.

```
import boto3
import csv

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = event['BUCKETNAME']
    key_name = event['KEYNAME']
    table_name = event['TABLENAME']
    recList=[]
    try:
        s3=boto3.client('s3')
        dyndb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
        content= s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
        recList = content['Body'].read().split('\n')
        firstrecord=True
        csv_reader = csv.reader(recList, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in csv_reader:
            if (firstrecord):
                firstrecord=False
                continue
            emp_id = row[0]
            emp_name = row[1].replace(',','').replace('$','') if row[1] else '-'
            company = row[2].replace(',','').replace('$','') if row[2] else '_'
            email = row[2].replace(',','').replace('$','') if row[2] else '_'
            response = dyndb.put_item(
                TableName=table_name,
                Item={
                'emp_id' : {'S':emp_id},
                'emp_name': {'S':emp_name},
                'company': {'S':company},
                'email': {'S':email},
                }
            )
        print('Put succeeded:')
    except Exception as e:
        print (str(e))
```

But when I invoke the lambda, execution is Successful but the importing not occurred and following error appears as function log.

```
Function Logs:
START RequestId: 5dcb3a35-d613-411e-be31-333a33c7ccd3 Version: $LATEST
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
END RequestId: 5dcb3a35-d613-411e-be31-333a33c7ccd3
REPORT RequestId: 5dcb3a35-d613-411e-be31-333a33c7ccd3  Duration: 1797.48 ms    Billed Duration: 1800 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 77 MB  Init Duration: 294.79 ms
```

In the above log,

1. What is the reason for `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`?
2. And is that the reason for not importing data to DynamoDB?
3. What should I do to resolve the issue and full fill my requirement?

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html ?

some string in your code should be converted to bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I looked into that and it was to read a JSON and import it into dynamoDB. I modified the code but it again gives the error `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict`!

Comment: Can somebody help on this please?!

Comment: I could resolve the issue by using `recList = file_content['Body'].read().decode().split('\r\n')` instead of`recList = file_content['Body'].read().split('\n')`