# Error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: while updating DynamoDB from CSV file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Below is the csv

```
1,'Chaks, Raj','$300,000', False
2,'Chen, Joe','$250,000', False
3,'Kumar, Harry','$240,000', True
```

Below is the code

```
import boto3
import csv
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    region='us-east-1'
    recList=[]
    try:            
        s3=boto3.client('s3')            
        dyndb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name=region)
        confile= s3.get_object(Bucket='csvfolder3', Key='employee.csv')
        recList = confile['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
        firstrecord=True
        csv_reader = csv.reader(recList, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in csv_reader:
            if (firstrecord):
                firstrecord=False
                continue
            empid = row[0]
            name = row[1].replace(',','').replace('$','') if row[1] else '-'
            salary = row[2].replace(',','').replace('$','') if row[2] else 0
            response = dyndb.put_item(
                TableName='emplist',
                Item={
                'empid' : {'N':str(empid)},
                'name': {'S':name},
                'salary': {'N':str(salary)},
                'parttime': {'BOOL':False},
                }
            )
        print('Put succeeded:')
    except Exception as e:
        print (str(e))
```

Below is the error thrown:

> a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

while updating from csv to DynamoDB

Error:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: Joe

Comment: similar question withour answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60932447/error-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-importing-csv-to-dynamod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your quotation marks.

The file contains:

```
1,'Chaks, Raj','$300,000', False
2,'Chen, Joe','$250,000', False
3,'Kumar, Harry','$240,000', True
```

However, you are telling `csv_reader` that the quotes are double-quotes:

```py
csv_reader = csv.reader(recList, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

So, simply change it to:

```py
csv_reader = csv.reader(recList, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")
```

Comment: FYI, this question was answered live on Twitch, watch Episode 8 here to see your question towards the end: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBFD3bw_QT1YVK_ptB6koLFbIAdXFHbHj

Comment: can you answer below `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62674331/how-to-public-access-of-elastic-vpc-endpoint`

Comment: I tried once this question, but same error it is going to public

Comment: Thanks John , i am a visitor of your youtube page can you answer below  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718650/how-to-write-a-lambda-handler-to-send-the-data-to-elastic-search