# How to public access of Elastic vpc endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I have create elastic service in AWS with `Dev Testing(t2 small)`

Detials shown below

```
VPCvpc-7620c30b
Security Groups
sg-7e9b1759
IAM RoleAWSServiceRoleForAmazonElasticsearchService
AZs and Subnets
us-east-1e: subnet-2f100a11
```

How to access my VPC endpoint  https://vpc-xxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com access from outside.

Kibana is below : https://vpc-xx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/

I am not running on Ec2 instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html):

> To access the default installation of Kibana for a domain that resides within a VPC, users **must have access to the VPC**. This process varies by network configuration, but likely involves connecting to a VPN or managed network or using a **proxy server**.

One way of setting up the proxy server has been explained in detail in the recent **AWS blog** post:

- [How do I use an NGINX proxy to access Kibana from outside a VPC that's using Amazon Cognito authentication?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kibana-outside-vpc-nginx-elasticsearch/)

The instruction could also be adapted to not using Congnito.

Extra links, with other, probably easier setup with **ssh tunnels**:

- [How to connect to AWS Elasticsearch cluster from outside of the VPC](https://dev.to/murat/how-to-connect-to-aws-elasticsearch-cluster-from-outside-of-the-vpc-5kb)
- [How To: Access Your AWS VPC-based Elasticsearch Cluster Locally](https://www.jeremydaly.com/access-aws-vpc-based-elasticsearch-cluster-locally/)
- [SSH Tunnel Access to AWS ElasticSearch Domain and Kibana | Howto](https://www.devopswiki.co.uk/wiki/elasticsearch/aws-elasticsearch-via-ssh-tunnel)
- [How can I use an SSH tunnel to access Kibana from outside of a VPC with Amazon Cognito authentication?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kibana-outside-vpc-ssh-elasticsearch/)

Comment: Is there any alternate blog/doc to follow. The above doc is high level flow.  Can you create and check once

Comment: @aysh I added few new links showing how to use `ssh tunnels` for the access. They are simpler than the nginx proxy.

Comment: Can you answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799901/how-to-create-invoke-same-lambda-function-for-the-two-api-gateway/62800180#62800180

Comment: @aysh Hi. Something wrong with the current answer in the new question?

Answer (score 1):

VPC endpoints are not accessible directly from outside of the VPC.

If you want to allow this you will need to use a proxy instance in your VPC that can connect to the VPC endpoint, then proxy all requests through the EC2 instance in order to access the endpoint.

More information is available [here](https://d0.awsstatic.com/aws-answers/Accessing_VPC_Endpoints_from_Remote_Networks.pdf).