# How to create invoke same lambda function for the two api-gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I aws create a 2 api-gateway

- First one

https://xx.xx-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/uploadapi/?search=all

then my lambda function will invoke below

```
searchone = es.search(index="my-index", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
return searchone
```

- Second One

https://xx.xx-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/uploadapi/?search=matchphrase=name_computer

```
searchtwo = es.search(index="my-index", body={"query": {"match": {"name":"computer"}}})
return searchtwo
```

Basically need to create `single` lambda function

if api url is first one then return `searchone` if the api url is second one then return `searchtwo`

Disclaimer ? DO i need to create separate Lambda function for above two api's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need multiple lambda functions. Among the two url's that you have specified, what changes is only the query params.

...?**search=all** 
...?**search=matchphrase=name_computer**

Search parameters are used for such conditions i.e. to notify the server if it needs to handle the request in some specific way. **You can access them in the lambda function.**

Before we move ahead, I would suggest you consider the following schema:

...?**search=all** -->  ?search_type=match_all
...?**search=matchphrase=name_computer** -> ...?**search_type=match_some&match_phrase=name_computer**

Now, if you explore the `event` object that is passed to the lambda function, you will find these query parameters at `event.requestContext.queryStringParameters`. It would look something like this:

```
{
    <...>
    'resource': '/v1/uploadapi',
    'requestContext': {
    'queryStringParameters': {
        'search_type': 'match_some',
        'match_phrase': 'name_computer'
    },
    <...>
}
```

You can now use this to build logic on top of it.